# Windows context menus on drives (using "AppliesTo")

Tags: windows, context-menu

I’m about to implement a disk shredding software that is also available via a explorer right menu.

I can add this via the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\Shredder key` (the "Shredder" is my new key, but by doing so, it is available on all drive letters, even C: (the system drive) or drive letters that point to network drives (where Shredding doesn’t work).

I’m not looking for a way to use the "AppliesTo" key to limit when this entry would be activated, and was thinking something along the lines of:

```
"AppliesTo"= "System.Volume.isLocalDrive AND System.Volume.IsNotSystemdrive"
```

but I cannot find any documentation on what’s available.
BitLocker uses something like this:

`"AppliesTo"="System.Volume.BitLockerProtection:=6"`, but the "System.Volume" itself is nowhere documented, the nearest I came was [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props.)

The Bitlocker method is briefly mentioned in [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers) (section Getting Dynamic Behavior for Static Verbs by Using Advanced Query Syntax), but nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

You may see what's available in the Microsoft article
[Windows Properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props).

Unfortunately, I can't find any value that helps with finding if a disk
is local or boot.

You might need to list the drives by their letters.